# Jsoup get redirected URL

Tags: java, jsoup, url-shortener

I'm trying to fetch the actual(redirected) url from the one provided by a url shortener.

Let's take twitter url shortener for example. I'm able to get the response object also parsed it to get the document.

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://t.co/i5dE1K4vSs")
                .followRedirects(true) //to follow redirects
                .execute();
```

Now, considering a single redirect, where to get the final url from? Any method or strategy to achieve this?

Comment: I think the `Connection.Base` class has an `url()` method

Comment: You want to get the final url or all the redirects?

Comment: Final Url. All the intermediate urls won't hurt either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Response object has a url() method which should give you the final url. So you could do like

```
String url = "http://t.co/i5dE1K4vSs";
Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(true).execute();
System.out.println(response.url())
```

If you want o get the intermediate redirects you should turn follow redirect off and then check for header "location". Eg

```
String url = "http://t.co/i5dE1K4vSs";
Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).followRedirects(false).execute();
System.out.println(response.header("location"));
```

If it has multiple redirect you need to recurssively call the urls.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
String originalUrl = Jsoup.connect("http://t.co/i5dE1K4vSs")
                        .followRedirects(true) //to follow redirects
                        .execute().url().toExternalForm();
System.out.println(originalUrl);
```

Output:

```
http://ibnlive.in.com/news/messi-considered-move-to-arsenal/487799-5-21.html
```

Explanation:

As the `Connection.Response` has `Connection.Base` as superinterface, you can just use the #url() method of it (and then use the `URL` object as you want.