# jsoup android java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find form

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to fetch data from a [food delivery website](https://deliveroo.fr/fr/) using `JSOUP`. The goal is to fill in the `address field`, click the `submit button` and show the response to the user. But when trying to find the form on the homepage I get **`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find form`**. `searchFormResponse.parse()` contains the homepage `HTML`, so the problem is not there. I already tried multiple ways of selecting the form from the `jsoup` website, but nothing seems to work. Any help will be much appreciated. If it has any importance, it's for an android app. Thanks in advance.

**Here is my code**

```
        final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36";
        final String LOGIN_FORM_URL = "https://deliveroo.fr/fr/"; //TODO make it adapt to the country
        final String myAddress = a;

// # Go to login page
        Connection.Response searchFormResponse = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_FORM_URL)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                .execute();

// # Fill the search form
// ## Find the search first...
        FormElement searchForm = (FormElement)searchFormResponse.parse()
                .select("div#landing-index-page-search__container > form").first();

// ## ... then "type" the address ...
        Element searchField = searchForm.select("#landing-index-page-search--input").first();
searchField.val(myAddress);


// # Now send the form
        Connection.Response loginActionResponse = searchForm.submit()
                .cookies(searchFormResponse.cookies())
                .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                .execute();
    System.out.println(loginActionResponse.parse().html());
```

**Part of the website code**

```
<div class="landing-index-page-search__container" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1">
    <h1 class="landing-index-page-search--main-title" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.0">Vos restaurants préférés, livrés en moins de 30 minutes.</h1>
    <form method="get" action="" class="landing-index-page-search--form landing-index-page-search--non-postcode" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2">
    <span data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.0"></span>
    <div data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1">
    <div class="landing-index-page-search--input" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1.1">
    <div class="landing-index-page-search--input address-search" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1.1.1">
    <input name="address_search" type="text" tabindex="-1" class="" placeholder="Saisissez votre adresse" value=" " data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1.1.1.0"/></div>
    <input id="find_food" type="submit" value="Voir les restaurants" class="button" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1.1.2"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is, that you try to select a `<div>` with the **id** `landing-index-page-search__container` with the line

```
FormElement searchForm = (FormElement)searchFormResponse.parse()
                .select("div#landing-index-page-search__container > form").first();
```

But as far as I can see, there is only a `<div>` with the **class** `landing-index-page-search__container`

The selection should be

```
FormElement searchForm = (FormElement)searchFormResponse.parse()
                    .select("div.landing-index-page-search__container > form").first();
```

The difference is, with the **#** you select by the `id` and with the **.** (dot), you select by the `class` of the element.

To select an Elements only by class, without knowing/mention the tag you can use:

```
Elements elements = searchForm.getElementsByClass("landing-index-page-search--input");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Another quick question may be you know the answer to, how do I get the url that was opened after I clicked the submit button?

Comment: I guess [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907808/jsoup-get-redirected-url) should help you