# How to get final redirected url with Jsoup if first url returns response status code 200

Tags: java, jsoup, httpurlconnection

I have a scenario where I need to get the final redirected url. I am trying to use Jsoup but unfortunately I can't get the final redirected url from it because the first url gives the responseCode 200 and the logic of Jsoup is that it will iterate for the next redirect url if the status code is 301 or something else. So unfortunately it stops on the first redirect url and does not iterate to the next url because on the first url itself the status code is 200.

I need to iterate the redirect url until I get the final or at least the second redirected url.

How can I achieve this?

My purpose is that I need to check whether a particular website has the valid Web Page Title or not which I want to extract from HTML DOM page title tag. Right now, the DOM returns null because the first url is blank and I am not able to redirect to final url.

Following is the code which I am using.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(redirectUrl).execute();
System.out.println(response.statusCode() + " : " + response.url());
String url = response.url().toString();

Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(5000).get();
String actualPageTitle = document.title();
System.out.println("Actual Page Title: " + actualPageTitle);
```

From this code, I am getting the exact same first url which I am passing as redirectUrl parameter and there is no redirection of the second or final url.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: See [Jsoup get redirected URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907808/jsoup-get-redirected-url)

Comment: Without seeing the actual urls you're using is hard to know what the response looks like. My first guess is if there is an actual redirect, it's happening in the first call and the url is already the redirected one when you call the second one. You could try to use chrome's developer inspector network tab to trace the actual responses